# Android Fragment Shared Elements not working with "add"

Tags: android, animation

I've been trying to make the Transition Animations work with Fragments, what I find weird (or maybe I'm not understanding something right) is that when using `replace` it works as expected, but when using `add` it doesn't...

WORKS:

```
EndFragment fragment = new EndFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .addSharedElement(imageView, imageTransitionName)
        .addSharedElement(textView, textTransitionName)
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit();
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
EndFragment fragment = new EndFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .addSharedElement(imageView, imageTransitionName)
        .addSharedElement(textView, textTransitionName)
        .add(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Got any solution? if we use add instead of replacing?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's doable. I hope someone corrects me though